# My IMAP account occasionally gives a timeout error

Tags: imap, apple-mail, osx-mavericks

I've got a few email addresses setup in Apple Mail. An iCloud address, one of my internet provider and one of my hosting company. The last one is giving me problems.

Every now and then when I go to Apple Mail I notice an exclamation mark next to that IMAP account. Clicking on it shows the popup message:

> The connection to the server "imap.example.com" on port 143 timed out.

The exclamation mark won't go away until I press the 'receive email' envelope button or restart Apple Mail. Then it works fine again. Later, every now and then, it will show that exclamation mark again and the same popup message. I've contacted my hosting company and they say every setting of that account is as it should be. From the log files they notice that Apple Mail tries to make about 3 connections every second when 1 would suffice, but that's probably because I've got 3 email accounts set up. I already deleted the account and reinstalled it again as I just updated to OSX Mavericks.

What is a 'timed out' in general about? And why does this message only appear on that particular email account and not the other two? How can I fix it or what could I check to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally a timeout error means that your email server need more time to fetch emails than there are set on your program. So the program will cause a socket error. Probably increasing the timeout configuration on Apple Mail can fix the problem.